# Why my map does not re-size correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a map, which does not re-size correctly. I have two pages: `#page1` which is shown at start-up and `#page2` which can be reached by a link in the tab.

On the `#page1` I init. the map:

```
var map;
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function () {
    // map init
    var mapOptions = {
        // karte wird initialisiert mit zoom aufs ruhrgebiet
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 7),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
});
```

then I added the code to resize the map when I get to the `#page2`:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page2', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");   
});
```

The problem is, when I get to `#page2` the first time the map has not the right size:
[image]

**How to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because **`data-role="content"`** is not resizing to cover all available space.

Use this CSS on your content div:

```
.ui-content {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Replace **`40px`** with **`0`** if you don't have header or footer.

Here's a great **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)** talking about Google maps V3 API implementation with jQuery Mobile. It contains working examples.

Comment: this does not fix it, still have the issue

Comment: its also strange, then I go back to page1 and then return to page2 its all fine.

Comment: Look at an examples found in a posted article. They should give you enough information to make this work. Or can you create a jsFiddle example, just put everything you have and I will sort it and make it work.